# Dojo TextArea - Number is Not a Function

Tags: javascript, forms, textarea, dojo

I'm getting a strange error. When I try to instantiate a TextArea I get Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function. However if instead I change it to a TextBox the code runs fine. I don't think I'm passing the constructor anything invalid, and I don't see any place in my code where TextArea is being overwritten. I don't use it in my code until I instantiate it in the else if block. Any ideas?

```
array.forEach(listOfFields, function(item) {
    if(item === "Recent Rain") {
        tr = domConstruct.create("tr", {}, "displayDataForm"),
        td = domConstruct.create("td", {}, tr),
        td1 = domConstruct.create("td", {}, tr),
         l = domConstruct.create("label", {
             innerHTML: 'Rain in Last 24 Hours?: ',
             'class': 'dataFieldLabel',
             'for': item
         }, td, 'first'),
         r = new DropDownSelect({
             'class': 'dataField',
             name: item,
             title: item,
             options: [
                        { label: "Yes", value: "Yes" },
                        { label: "No", value: "No", selected: true },
                      ],
             'data-fieldType': 'DropDownSelect'
         }).placeAt(td1, 'last');
    }
    else if(item === 'Water Color or Odor' || item === 'Aquatic Life Present' || item === 'Site Change') {
        tr = domConstruct.create("tr", {}, "displayDataForm"),
        td = domConstruct.create("td", {}, tr),
        td1 = domConstruct.create("td", {}, tr),
         l = domConstruct.create("label", {
             innerHTML: item + ': ',
             'class': 'dataFieldLabel',
             'for': item
         }, td, 'first'),
         r = new TextArea({
             'class': 'dataField',
             name: item,
             title: item,
             'data-fieldType': 'TextArea'
         }).placeAt(td1, 'last');
    }
    else {
     tr = domConstruct.create("tr", {}, "displayDataForm"),
        td = domConstruct.create("td", {}, tr),
        td1 = domConstruct.create("td", {}, tr),
         l = domConstruct.create("label", {
             innerHTML: item + ': ',
             'class': 'dataFieldLabel',
             'for': item
         }, td, 'first'),
         r = new TextBox({
             'class': 'dataField',
             name: item,
             title: item,
             'data-fieldType': 'TextBox'
         }).placeAt(td1, 'last');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my full list of dependencies:

```
        require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/ready", "dojo/request", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/array", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/TextArea", "dojox/form/DropDownSelect", "dojo/json", "dijit/registry", "dojo/query"],

                function(dom, ready, request, domConstruct, domAttr, declare, array, Dialog, DateTextBox, Form, Button, Checkbox, TextBox, TextArea, DropDownSelect, JSON, registry, query)
```

I'm using dijit/form/TextArea

Comment: are you using dijit/form/textarea or dojox/mobile/textarea?

Comment: Can you post your dependency list and the function that is invoked when the dependencies are resolved?

Comment: Just posted what you guys were asking for